# Get a node's attribute value in Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XML data structure that looks like this

```
<menu>
   <sport id="1580" name="Foo" />
   <sport id="1581" name="Bar" />
   ...
```

In XSL, I need to select the appropriate `<sport>` node via the `id` attribute and print out the `name` attribute. I'm selecting the node via this expression

```
{document('foo.xml')/menu/sport[@id = $id]
```

which works just fine, but can't figure out how to get the `name` attribute on the same element. Doing

```
{document('odkazy.xml')/menu/sport[@id = $id]/@name
```

doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: i use xsl:value-of to print it out, and the parser throws "error: invalid expression"

Comment: Why do you start the expression with a curly bracket? Show more of your XSLT code. Which version of XSLT do you work with?

Comment: jeez, the brackets. i'm outputting the stuff into html, and was using the brackets on html attributes and forgot to take them out on xsl elements. want to post an answer so i can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the trailing curly bracket at the beginning of your XPath expression. Change

```
<xsl:value-of select="{document('odkazy.xml')/menu/sport[@id = $id]/@name"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('odkazy.xml')/menu/sport[@id = $id]/@name"/>
```

---

Curly brackets can be used in XSLT, too. But they denote an attribute value template:

```
<element name="{document('odkazy.xml')/menu/sport[@id = $id]/@name}"/>
```

[This](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) is the relevant part of the XSLT specification that explains attribute value templates.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not set a variable to the id, or even a for-each, to set you to the correct sport. and then just output the name;

```
<xsl:variable name="sportName" select="document('odkazy.xml')/menu/sport[@id = $id]" />
<xsl:value-of select ="$sportName/@name"/>
```

Not sure how well the below would work but worth a try maybe?

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('odkazy.xml')/menu/sport[@id = $id]">
<xsl:value-of select ="@name"/>
</xsl:for-each/>
```

May all be nonsense as i can't really see why

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('odkazy.xml')/menu/sport[@id = $id]/@name"/>
```

would not work

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i used curly brackets in the select attribute.

Comment: This answer does not point to the source of error. Variables work as well, same as for-each - but this is not the problem.

Comment: The final line of my suggestions lines up with how you answered the question. as i said i couldn't see why that would not work, however i had just deleted the { in my mind without even realizing i had!